# Style data and Export it to CSV using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv

```
$scope.exportData = function ($searchProductDetails) {
    alasql('SELECT * INTO CSV("searchProductDetails.CSV",?) FROM ?',[$searchProductDetails]);
        };

searchProductDetails = [
   {
     "@search.score": 1.634418,
     "brandName": "Aashirvaad",
     "productId": "16361",
     "highLevelCategory": "Food",
     "lowLevelCategory": "Flour / Atta",
     "subCategory": "Wheat Flour / Atta",
     "productName": "Aashirvaad Sharbati Atta",
     "productImageUrl": "Cooking_Aashirvaad-Sharbati-Atta.jpg",
     "P1PKBrandsId": 10009
    },
    {
     "@search.score": 1.5750113,
     "brandName": "Pillsbury",
     "productId": "22017",
     "highLevelCategory": "Food",
     "lowLevelCategory": "Flour / Atta",
     "subCategory": "Wheat Flour / Atta",
     "productName": "Pillsbury Chakki Fresh Atta",
     "productImageUrl": "Cooking_Pillsbury-Chakki-Fresh-Atta.jpg",
     "P1PKBrandsId": 10823
    }
]
```

I don't want to export `@search.score`, `P1PKBrandsId` and `productImageUrl` but now I can export all and I need export in CSV format only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [REMOVE COLUMNS](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Remove-Columns) modifier. AlaSQL will remove all unnecessary columns for you. Try this code:

```
$scope.exportData = function ($searchProductDetails) {
    alasql('SELECT * REMOVE COLUMNS [@search.score], P1PKBrandsId, \
         productImageUrl INTO CSV("searchProductDetails.CSV",{headers:true}) FROM ?',
         [$searchProductDetails]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code:

```
var productData = angular.copy(searchProductDetails);  
var finalJson =[];  
angular.forEach(productData, function(obj) {
            finalJson.push({"brandName": obj.brandName, 
                "productId": obj.productId,
                "highLevelCategory": obj.highLevelCategory,
                "lowLevelCategory": obj.lowLevelCategory,
                "subCategory": obj.subCategory,
                "productName": obj.productName,
            });
        });
```